# Copy a formula skipping multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to know how to copy a formula that skips a number of rows. For example, E40-E1, E80-E40, E120-E80, E160-E120, etc. Basically I only want the values every 40th row. I would run a macro to delete the the rows in between, but there's 15,000 rows.

Comment: you can use Offset function

Answer (score 1):

As long as the number of rows you're skipping remains constant, you can simply select 39 blank rows, and the one with your formula and autofill down. Excel will automatically skip rows.